# Django Up/Down Voting how to make template?

Tags: django, voting

Django noob here. I have installed [updown package](https://github.com/weluse/django-updown) and followed the instructions to add it on my UserPic model. Here are relevant parts:

```
class UserPic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    picfile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_uplaod_file_name)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = RatingField(can_change_vote=True)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',  
    url(r"^(?P<object_id>\d+)/rate/(?P<score>[\d\-]+)$", AddRatingFromModel(), {
            'app_label': 'userpic',
            'model': 'UserPic',
            'field_name': 'rating',
        }, name="pic_rating"),
    rl(r'^(?P<pic_id>\d+)/$', 'userpics.views.photo'),  
    url(r'^(?P<pic_id>\d+)/delete$', 'userpics.views.del_photo'),
    url(r'^/$', 'userpics.views.list'),
```

)

views.py

```
def photo(request, pic_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pic = UserPic.objects.get(pk=pic_id)
        hasNext=False
        hasPrev=False
        picOwner=False

        next = int(pic_id) + 1
        prev= int(pic_id) - 1

        if pic.user== request.user:
            picOwner= True
        try:
            if UserPic.objects.get(pk=next):
                hasNext =True
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if UserPic.objects.get(pk=prev):
                hasPrev = True 
        except:
            pass

        message = pic_id
        return render_to_response('userpics/photo.html',
                                      {'pic':pic, 'hasNext':hasNext, 'hasPrev':hasPrev, 'picOwner':picOwner},
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

photo.html

```
{% if pic %}

<form method="post" action="/photo/{{pic.id}}/rate/1" >
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="button" value="Up">
</form>

<form method="post" action="/photo/{{pic.id}}/rate/-1" >
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="button" value="Down">
</form>

Rating {{pic.rating}}
 <img class="pic" src="/static/assets/{{pic}}" />
```

However the buttons that are created don't seem to work. And in place of {{pic.rating}} I get things like:

```
Rating <updown.fields.RatingManager object at 0x7f5c64404990>
```

Unfortunately the docs is less than fool-proof so I appreciate your help to implement the app.

Comment: Can you add the view too?

Comment: Its showing `Rating <updown.fields.RatingManager object at 0x7f5c64404990>` because, its not a integer field. If that's what you were expecting.

Comment: so how to make digit to appear? This is one of my questions actually.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know this app. But what you can do is use an `boolean field` or an `integer field`. Or better, you can try [this](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it doesn't look like django-updown even exposes a "total" rating, only number of upvotes and downvotes. you can get at these with:

```
{{ pic.rating.likes }} and {{ pic.rating.dislikes }}
```

Comment: You just need buttons that post to "<object_id>/vote/1" and "<object_id>/vote/-1"